# How do I send files to a remote computer?

Tags: node.js, file-transfer

I need to send big files from a node server to a client and need to send this data to a remote computer. I have written this code, what should I do so that data can be streamed to the other computer?

```
var fs = require ('fs');
var http = require ('http'); 
var path = require ('path');

http.createServer (function (req, res) {
    var filePath = path.join ('/home/cortana/Videos' + '/Annabelle.2014.HC.HDRip.XViD.AC3-juggs[ETRG].avi');
    var stat = fs.statSync (filePath);
    res.writeHead (200, {
        'Content-Type' : 'video/avi', 
        'Content-Length' : stat.size
    });
    var readStream = fs.createReadStream (filePath);
    readStream.pipe (res);

}).listen (8999, '0.0.0.0');
```

Comment: In case if you're making a webserver to stream video to a client, you might wanna check [quickstream](https://www.npmjs.com/package/quickstream). I  use it, to watch movies on my phone with vlc, where the big files exists on my computer.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can use some sort of streaming library like [binary.js](http://binaryjs.com/) 
All you need to do is simply to implement client and server like shown on the library's tutorial. The only difference is that you don't run your client in browser, but on node.js instead.

Your other option would be creating TCP client and server apps like [here](https://gist.github.com/tedmiston/5935757)